# Alerta ao fechar o navegador

Tags: javascript

Como eu faria para que aparecesse um alerta ao fechar o navegador, consegui um, porém ele dá o alerta  também  ao mudar as abas e não é isso que quero no momento....

Obrigado!

Comment: Quer que apareca a mensagem quando fechar a aba tbm?

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se ajuda... mas podes utilizar este metodo... o unico problema é que vai ser executado ao fazer refresh, etc...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = confirmar_saida;

function confirmar_saida()
{
    return 'Vamos ter saudades suas!';
}
</script>

Olá! :D
```

Comment: Certo  Tiago. Mas tem como direcionar para outra página?

Comment: Nesse caso podes utilizar o window.location para redirecionar...

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location ao clicar em um botão   
function redirecionar(){ 
    alert("Você será redirecionado"); 
    window.location="sair.php/"; 
}
```

Ou

```js
function funcao() {
 var r = confirm('Quer mesmo sair?');;

 if (r == true) {
    window.location.assign("http://www.globo.com") /* ou o seu sair.php */
 } 
else {
    alert('Nao funcionou');
}
 return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return funcao();">Sair do sistema</a>
```

Comment: Perfeito Paulo. Como eu faria para redirecionar para outra página? colocar embaixo do return window.location.href='pagina.html'?

Comment: Como vc vai redirecionar se vai fechar o navegador? N entendi...

Comment: No sistema, o usuário ao se logar o status fica online, porém quando ele clicar em "Sair" do sistema, direciono ele para a página inicial e mudo o status para offline. Só que muitos usuários estão fechando diretamente pelo navegador e o status fica online, mesmo ele não estando... precisaria de que aparecesse a mensagem e redirecionasse para a página de sair. Como acontece por exemplo em sites de banco quando apertamos o F5

Comment: Tá. Entendi, vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: Consegui o código que coloquei, porém ao acessar o site, ele já aparece a mensagem...

Comment: Ver agora como ficou :)

Comment: Oi Paulo. Então, na verdade seria ao sair do navegador ou fechar a aba onde está o sistema... coloquei o onunload() no body, mas nao funcionou

Comment: coloquei tb onbeforeunload() no body, também não funcionou.

Comment: Acho q tua lógica tá errada amigo. Como vou redirecionar o usuário se ele eu clico em sair do sistema? Eu acho que o certo eh fazer como eu mostrei no exemplo :)

Comment: Tente refazer usando o método que mostrei na resposta, acho q o sistema ficará até mais consistente.

Comment: Certo Paulo. Na verdade ao clicar no botão sair do sistema já existe uma mensagem de confirmação. Só que não estou conseguindo colocar essa mensagem ao fechar o navegador ou aba do navegador, senão o usuário permanecerá online, mesmo não estando mais....

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei, acho que com jquery funciona..Estou procurando uma solução e postar aqui...

Comment: Consegui esse código em jquery, mas não está funcionando:

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    // Your code and validation
    if (confirm) {
        return "Are you sure?";
    }
});