# Exibir uma <div> quando clicar no fechar da janela do navegador

Tags: jquery

Alguém sabe como eu faria para exibir uma `<div>` que está oculta quando o usuário clicar no botão de fechar a janela do navegador?

Comment: Fiz o teste e a página exibi a div e fecha, seria possível não fechar a página, mas sim só exibir a div?

Comment: não, a não ser que você crie um plugin para o navegador que faça isso.

Comment: O que se faz é diferente, mostrar antes de fechar, ao sair com o mouse pela parte superior da tela. Por sinal um treco muito chato. (Se interessar, dê uma pesquisada, isso ja foi perguntado no site).

Comment: Concordo, mas preciso exibir uma div com uma mensagem dizendo que o usuário não preencheu todos os dados, se ele quer realmente fechar o navegador.

Comment: Acredito que você poderia exibir um alert ou algo do tipo antes de sair

Comment: Então, é mais fácil avisar na hora que sair com o mouse, pq dá mais tempo de ver. Talvez para o seu caso seja o caso de perguntar se confirma fechar. E isso já tem resposta no site também, de como pedir confirmação.

Comment: Seria muito bacana, poderia me orientar como produzir?

Comment: Aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62571/70

Comment: Tem essa tb: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71128/70

Comment: Postei uma solução, mas como o @Bacco informou, já existem varias soluções para esse problema no SOpt ou no SO

Comment: @MunirBaarini sei que já lhe apontaram bons links, mas gostaria que se puder desse uma olhada nesta minha resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113155/3635, nela eu explico como o unonload/beforeunload funcionam de fato e como sites tipo facebook fazem para exibir uma "div".

Comment: Entendi Guilherme, então não é possível personalizar o modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso você poderia executar um javascript que exiba um alert ou um modal para isso, ex:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
  var message = 'Você tem certeza que deseja sair?';
  if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
    event = window.event;
  }
  if (event) {
    event.returnValue = message;
  }
  return message;
}

</script>
```

Documentação sobre o evento beforeunload.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: eu preciso exibir uma janela personalizada, por isso pensei em uma <div>

Comment: fazer o modal é tranquilo, o problema é chama-lo quando clicar no botão fechar do browser e só exibir o modal sem fechar o browser

Comment: existem algumas limitações de que se pode executar no beforeunload, tem que ver se ele permite executar um modal dentro dele.

Comment: Pessoal muito obrigado a todos!

Comment: @MunirBaarini segue a documentação do evento https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Muito obrigado Jefferson!